# My centered text moves to the next line when I increase font size and letter spacing

Tags: css, text, font-size

I want my text to be centered in the middle of the webpage, and it is, that is until I increase the size and letter spacing to what I want. When I do this, the second word moves to the next line even though I have 0 padding and there is plenty of room. Please help. Here is the css for my text:

```
.centered {
    font-family: Seravek;
    font-size: 500%;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: .16em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: you should add more code. it increases chance to get help

Answer (score 0):

This might help you centering your text, I used here `font-size: 500%;` that I find it really much, but you can make it smaller and everything will be fine with centering your text.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

main div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  letter-spacing: .18em;
  font-size: 500%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  
  <div>
    Center me - Center me -Center me - Center me - Center me - Center me -Center me - Center me - Center me - Center me - Center me - Center me -Center me - Center me
  </div>
  
</main>
```